# Is it ok to have many console.log()?

Tags: node.js, logging

I want my application to have a "debug" mode that will print to the console every thing happening but putting many console.log calls is kinda polluting my source code, so is it a good practice to have a debug mode like this?

For example:

```
function doSomething() {
    // ...
    console.log("Did something");
}
```

I really need this debug mode because my function are called on events and it's difficult to trace what's happening and there are many possible scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

1. Does your logging somehow "pollute" your source code?  Not if the logging helps your future self or someone else understand your code.  (Of course, don't allow your logging to have side-effects:  No `console.log( variable++ )`
2. Is console logging good for programs put into production?  No, not really. You should consider adopting a logging package.

I like [Winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston). There are plenty of other good packages; hopefully fans of those will write their own answers.

It allows you to send your log entries to files, to your *nix machine's `syslog` subsystem or to Windows Events or whatever, and to other places. It timestamps them if you want, and identifies which program they came from.  Your `console.log('current value', q)` operation becomes `logger.info('current value', q)` and your `console.error()` becomes `logger.error()`.

For a long-lived program (one that will still be used a few months from now) it is definitely worth your trouble to climb up the logger learning curve and rig up a solid logging system. If your program will run as part of a larger system, ask somebody how other parts of the system handle logging, and use the same scheme.